# Generate different access token scopes from 1 refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, identityserver3

Is there a way to generate from 1 refresh token several access tokens, each having different scope? As far as is found in my research that using 1 refreh token once we downgrade the scope of an access token we cannot upgrade it again, but i need to check if there is another workaround to downgrade and then upgrade the scope again using the same refresh token.

References

https://curity.io/resources/tutorials/getting-started/flows/refresh-tokens/

https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/issues/25

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/endpoints/token.html

https://www.pingidentity.com/en/company/blog/posts/2019/oauth2-access-token-multiple-resources-usage-strategies.html

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you need this?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg i need it for permissions purposes for SSO with a 3rd party,in the same session using a refresh token i need to be able to generate an access token with full scope for the user and another access token with lesser scopes for the 3rd party.. but i need to be able to keep generating new access tokens with full scope after generating an access token with lesser scope

Comment: Did you take a look at [Extension Grants](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html)?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg yes i need the refresh token grant to have the functionality that i mentioned